# Selecting from multiple subtables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have a table called meeting, and one called meeting_permissions. The latter stores what users took part in any given meeting. I also have other tables: note, discussion, conclusion, and topic, that store specific items for that meeting's transcript. What I want to do, is get all of the meetings that a specific user took part in, along with all of the associated notes, discussions, conclusions, and topics. Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM meeting WHERE id IN
(SELECT meeting_id FROM meeting_permissions WHERE user_id = $user) 
LEFT JOIN conclusion ON meeting.id = conclusion.meeting_id 
LEFT JOIN discussion ON meeting.id = discussion.meeting_id 
LEFT JOIN note ON meeting.id = note.meeting_id 
LEFT JOIN topic ON meeting.id = topic.meeting_id
```

That doesn't work for me. It breaks on the second left join. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: JOINS should be before the were - also this seems you can do this with one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JOIN against your subselection instead your main meeting table:

```
SELECT 
  meeting.*,
  conclusion.*
  discussion.*,
  note.*,
  topic.*
FROM meeting 
  LEFT JOIN conclusion ON meeting.id = conclusion.meeting_id 
  LEFT JOIN discussion ON meeting.id = discussion.meeting_id 
  LEFT JOIN note ON meeting.id = note.meeting_id 
  LEFT JOIN topic ON meeting.id = topic.meeting_id
WHERE meeting.id IN
  (SELECT mp.meeting_id FROM meeting_permissions mp WHERE mp.user_id = $user)
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.*, note.*, topic.* FROM meeting LEFT JOIN conclusion ON meeting.id = con' at line 4"

Comment: Disregard that. It was just one missing comma.

Comment: Sorry for the missing comma, I do typos :(